# MongoDB: flattern arrays QUIZ

Tags: mongodb

I have some data about users viewed and buyed some items. There's my mongodb collection example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("blah"),
    "user" : "u1111",
    "items_viewed" : ["i1111", "i12345"],
    "items_buyed" : ["i12345"]
}
```

I want a flattern version like in example below:

```
{
     "user" : "u1111",
     "item" : "i1111",
     "buyed": 0
}

{
     "user" : "u111",
     "item" : "i12345",
     "buyed" : 1
}
```

If the item was in items_buyed array it should have 1 in "buyed" field, if it was only in "items_viewed" - 0.

Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Learn about aggregate function and rewind in mongodb

Answer (score 1):

```
// Aggregation Pipeline Stages
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $match: {
            "_id" : "1"
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$items_viewed",
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $project: {
            "item" :  "$items_viewed",
            "buyed" : {
                        $cond: { 
                          if: {
                             $in: [ "$items_viewed" , "$items_buyed" ] 
                          }, then: 1, else: 0 }
                      }
        }
    },

]
```

);

Answer (score 0):

everyone, again!

I found another answer which allows absence of bought items. Here it is:

```
[//Aggregation pipeline
 {
    $unwind: { path : "$items_viewed" }
 },
 {
    $project: {
        "user" : 1,
        "item":  "$items_viewed",
        "buyed": { $in: [ "$items_viewed", { $ifNull: [ "$items_buyed", [] ] } ] }
 }        
}]
```

Thanks previous answer for good idea!